# How to delete from recently delete album iOS8

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I want to delete images in recently deleted album. Tried:

```
private ap[PHPhotoLibrary setDelets]
```

Doesn't work. Is there perhaps a private API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think this is possible because that wouldn't be something that the user expect and really want. It was created intentionally to have the possibility to revert *mistake* deletion. If any private api exists for that your app will be rejected if used during the review process of App Store.

Comment: I noticed that there is some way to use private api and upload to AppStore successfullly.It's not the problem.I just want to know if how to delete~

Comment: they let sometimes to use it for cases like setting up colors in search bars or something which wasn't harmful to the user (but still that can be a reason for a rejection). What you want to do is harmful to the user do not expect Apple will help you bring bad user experience to the platform :P I would be really sad if some app would mess in my photos (especially if it deletes it)

Comment: sorry mate :) Accepted answer?